# Registering Slim's PHP-View in PHP-DI6

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim, php-di

I'm trying to learn the Slim framework and PHP-DI at the same time. I don't want folks to write my code for me, but I'm at a complete stand-still here. All I want to do is figure out how to pass Slim's PHP-View object into a controller class using PHP-DI's Slim Bridge. From there, I'll mess about and figure things out. But I can't even get that to work. I'm thinking the Codecourse tutorial I've been watching is perhaps out of date, because it doesn't work either, and it used Twig to boot, which I'd prefer to avoid for the time being, as it's just one more thing I have to  learn... Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the [PHP-DI Slim Bridge](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge)? Also read the [PHP-DI Slim 3 Tutorial](http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/slim.html)

Comment: Yes, I've added the PHP-DI Slim Bridge dependencies thru Composer, but I can't seem to adapt any of the tutorials to allow me to inject Slim's PHP-View into a controller class. Am I close:

Comment: ` class App extends \DI\Bridge\Slim\App {
  protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $builder) {
   //$builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__.'/config/di-container.php');
   $definitions = [
    \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer::class => function(ContainerInterface $container) {
     $view = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer(__DIR__ . '\..\resources\views');
     return $view;
    } ,
   ];
   $builder->addDefinitions($definitions);
  }
 }`

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out how to do a code block in the comments...

Comment: Edit your question with the code you post in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Slim components are configured with Pimple service providers, those won't work with PHP-DI. If you want to use Twig then you have to create it manually (see [the Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html#basic-api-usage)).

Here is an example:

```
return [
    Twig_Environment::class => function () {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
        return new Twig_Environment($loader, [
            'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
        ]);
    },
];
```

Then you can inject the `Twig_Environment` class.

Here is a more generic/configurable example: https://github.com/stratifyphp/twig-module/blob/master/res/config/config.php

Comment: Thanks, but  I want to use PHP-View. I'm already trying to learn two new things, i don't want to add Twig to the list just yet. I only mentioned Twig because the tutorial I was watching about the Slim PHP-DI Bridge used Twig, and I was trying to modify it to use the PHP-View component instead.

Comment: Are you saying that there is **no way** to use Slim's PHP-View component with PHP-DI? If so, I'll shift gears I guess.

Comment: Just saw you'd come here from the Gitter Chat. Thank you so much. I'm now understanding that the PHP-View component won't work with PHP-DI, so I am starting to come to terms with the fact that I need to use another template engine. :) Will play with it today, as I'm sitting in jury pool at Los Angeles Court House. :)

Comment: @ConleeC I don't understand why you made a conclusion that PHP-View can't work with PHP-DI. PHP-View does not assume anything except that it requires `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` to work. So the example with Twig I believe wil also work wih Php-View. You just need to type-hint `PhpRenderer` class.

Comment: Also AFAIK Slim view uses Twig right? The component is just a pre-configured instance of Twig, which is configurable manually with a few lines of code as shown above.